# Visit a URL in PHP or javascript in background

Tags: php, url

I write my scripts in PHP, and there are HTML and javascripts inside. What I want is when I click a button(in HTML), it calls a javascript function, the function should visit a url like "http://localhost/1/2" And the page stays as before. Is it feasible?

I just want it work, no matter in js or php. Thanks.

Comment: Is it on the same domain? Do you need the resultant page?

Comment: you ask of ajax but it sounds like a homework. your code?

Comment: it is on the same domain. I dont need the resultant page, just visit it as like in background. what if it is not on the same domain?

Comment: hah~ it's not homework. my code is simple: a html button calls a javascript function and in that function I add alert("<?php function()?>"), php function is working. So I think whether in javascript or php, it can be added for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the page is on the same domain, you may use an Ajax request:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send(null);
```

Note that this does not do any error-checking, however. If you need that, there are a multitude of available tutorials easily found with a search.

---

And since you ask, for pages not on the same domain, using an `<iframe>` is sometimes possible:

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.src = url;
frame.style.position = "relative";
frame.style.left = "-9999px";
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly known as AJAX (being able to send a request to the server and receive a response back without navigating away from the page).

AJAX is supported in ALL modern browsers, but sometimes there are inconsistencies, so it is best to use a javascript framework such as [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com) or another framework.

I tend to use YUI, so here's a quick example on how to send an AJAX request using YUI. This uses the [IO Utility](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/):

```
// Create a YUI instance using io module.
YUI().use("io", function(Y) {
    var uri = "http://localhost/1/2";

    // Define a function to handle the response data.
    function complete() {
        Y.log('success!');
    };

    // Subscribe to event "io:complete"
    Y.on('io:complete', complete);

    // Make an HTTP request to 'get.php'.
    // NOTE: This transaction does not use a configuration object.
    var request = Y.io(uri);
});
```